# In JavaScript, how to update just one value from a JSON array when POSTing with fetch?

Tags: javascript, json, fetch-api

Having a method `getCustomer(id)`, that returns JSON from an API

```
{
    "id": 29,
    "name": "Rob",
    "checkin_status": false,  
}
```

I am trying to write update method that changes only the checkin status of that customer using fetch:

```
function checkIn(id) {

  url = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/customers/update_customer/" + id
 
  var data = new getCustomer(id);
  
  for( var k = 0; k < data.length; ++k ) {
    if( data[k]['job_checked_in'] == false ) {
      console.log("job_checked_in is false");
      data[k]['job_checked_in'] = true ;
    }
    else {
      console.log('job_checked_in was true');
    }
  }

  fetch(url, {
    method: "POST",
    body: JSON.stringify(data),
    headers: {
      'Content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'
    }
  })
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(json => console.log(json))

}
```

but for loop doesn't seem to work.

How can I fix it, or is there a better way to replace a single value in a JSON array when POSTing to an API? I tried posting a single key/value pair and not the full array and it posted but it did not work on server side.

Comment: what does `getCustomer()` do? Are you sure you're getting back a non-empty array?

Comment: Also what **exactly** does "doesn't seem to work" mean? Does *anything* happen? Do your `console.log()` calls print anything? Are errors reported?

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly, you'd like to change the checkin status of the user which has the id passed as argument to the checkIn function.

First, you are not checking that the user to update must have the same id as the one passed in the function.

Moreover, you should use .findIndex() method instead of iterating through the array until you find the correct user:

```
const userIndex = data.findIndex( user => user.id === id);
if(userIndex !== -1) {
    data[userIndex].checkin_status = true;
} else {
    // handle error for no user found
}
```

However I am not sure about why you should post the entire array to the endpoint to update just a single user. It would be helpful to know how the server-side endpoint works and why posting only one user is not working.